# Youtube API v3 always return error 403 (accessNotConfigured)

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I have read a lot of answers to fix this error, like using **browser key** instead of android key but none of them work.

I have turned on `YouTube Data API v3` on my developer console and i already generated an API Key for android.

This is the example URL :

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=PLAYLISTID&fields=items&key=ANDROID_API_KEY

It returns this error :

```
{
error: {
errors: [
{
domain: "usageLimits",
reason: "accessNotConfigured",
message: "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
}
],
code: 403,
message: "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
}
}
```

**I have activated the API, but it keeps telling me to activate it**. What should i do?

And in the projects list view on my developer console, this project already has 10 request and 10 errors.

The error said "Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project.", **does that mean i need to publish/do some settings one the developer console** after i turned on the API in the Google API Console?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: are you showing youtube video in youtube player from youtube.xxx.jar file??

Comment: @IllegalArgument Yes, i tried to use Youtube player from their jar. But this error happened even before that, i just tried to get a list of video on a playlist. Please help me out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe there is a bug in Google's system.

I need to use the **browser apps key** instead of android key.

And that is not enough, i need to open the old console, yes **JUST OPEN** :

https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0/?noredirect

The **funny** part is, i dont have to do anything, just open that old console...even the generated key is the same, so basically there should be not problem. So funny for wasting my time, Hope this help you.

Comment: This works for me as well.  When prompted to provide allowed referral websites, leaving blank will allow all referers, including android apps apparently.

Comment: @DJElbow no..i use browser key until now

Answer (score -2):

Here's how to fix [app could not be downloaded due to an error 403](http://appslova.com/android-fix-app-could-not-be-downloaded-due-to-an-error-403/):

#### Method 1: The most common fix for most Android market or Google Play related errors.

Go to `system settings-> Accounts->Google->remove your Gmail account
Now from settings->Apps->All->Force Stop`, Clear data and cache for Google Play Store, Google Service Framework and Download Manager (like in method 1)
Now again go to `settings->Accounts->Google->Add your Gmail account`
Restart your android and then accept all the Google terms and setup Google settings
Rerun Google Play Store and update or install your app.

#### Method 2-Clearing Proxy:

Go to `Settings->Wireless and Networks->More->Mobile Networks
APN (Access Point Name)->MOWAP->Edit`
Select `clear Proxy option`
Try to re-run the installation in Google Play Store

#### Method 3-Router Proxy Settings:

Open your router configuration or settings panel (example- typing 192.168.1.1 on the browser brings up the router settings on my TP-Link router)
Now find your `filter settings->Uncheck Proxy`
If that didn’t work  also `uncheck Cookies box` from the `filter settings`
Now install your app from Google Play

#### Method 4- Alternative Google account

Create another Google account if you currently have only one account
Open `Google Play Store->Press Menu button->Accounts->select the alternative Gmail account`
Now try installing the app

#### Method 5- Browser Fix:  I found this solution on Phonebuff.com.

1. Go to play.google.com on your Computer’s web browser (preferably Google Chrome).
2. Sign into your Google account (by hitting the sign-in button at the top right).
3. Search for the app you wish to purchase and download.
4. Open the app’s page up by clicking the title link.
5. On the “install” or “purchase” button, right click and press “inspect element.”
6. Above the row that will be highlighted, you’ll see several lines of code. Locate the `data-ispurchased = 'true'` code (near the bottom of the paragraph).
   Double click on the `true` in data-is purchased=”true” and change it to `false` then press enter on your keyboard.
7. Now click on `installed` or `purchased` to buy the app as you normally would

Comment: This has nothing to do with the original question. The question is about accessing the YouTube Data API from an app, not about downloading an app.