# Youtube API Request, Service Error 403

Tags: java, android, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

In my application, I am attempting to fetch Channel data, such as total number of video uploads and subscriber count. However, when running my application, I encounter the following error:

> E/Service Error:: 403 : The request did not specify any Android package name or signing-certificate fingerprint. Please ensure that the client is sending them or use the API Console to update your key restrictions.

As far as obtaining OAuth Credentials, I have followed several guides, including the guides provided on the [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application#Create_API_Keys) webpage:

1. Navigated to my `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101\bin` directory and opened this location in a terminal window.
2. Input the following command `keytool -list -v - keystore "C:\Users\[PATH_TO_ANDROIDDEBUGKEY].keystore"`. Used **android** as the password.
3. On the API Console :

   - Created Credentials, and for key restriction, selected **Android Apps**
   - Copied the SHA-1 fingerprint and pasted into the API Console. Also typed in my applications package name (found in my AndroidManifest.xml file).
4. Saved settings.

I copied the API key into my application, and always access it statically.
ie:

```
youtube = new YouTube.Builder(...).setYouTubeRequestInitializer(new YouTubeRequestInitializer(Config.YOUTUBE_API_KEY)).setApplicationName("MY_APPLICATION_NAME").build();

YouTube.Channels.List query = youtube.channels().list("statistics");
query.setKey(Config.YOUTUBE_API_KEY);
query.setFields("items(statistics(subscriberCount,videoCount))");
ChannelListResponse response = query.execute();
```

So I have no idea why I am encountering the error above when I have completed the steps correctly? This issue was [previously discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39543105/youtube-api-key), but the answer selected is not what I was expecting, as I would like to have Key Restriction.

---

**Other Steps I Have Taken to Resolve the Service Error**

- Generated my owned signed APK and keystore. I followed the same steps provided above (changing the keystore path) to obtain the SHA-1 fingerprint and pasted into the API Console ---> *Did not resolve*
- Created an entirely new API Key and followed the steps provided above ---> *Did not resolve*
- Used this terminal command instead to obtain the SHA-1 Fingerprint : `keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore [path-to-debug-or-production-keystore] -list -v`  ---> *Did not resolve*
- Ensured the Youtube Data API v3 is enabled on the API Manager Dashboard ---> *Did not resolve*

Can anyone please provide an answer as to why I am receiving a Service Error if I have followed the credential steps listed in the guides?

Comment: Well, I don't know if this is a bug or not. But according to this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740251/youtube-api-v3-always-return-error-403-accessnotconfigured) it might be a bug in the Google System. The only workaround that I see in the internet for this issue is by using a Browser key instead of Android key.
If you have time, try also to check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33989062/restricting-usage-for-an-android-key-for-a-google-api) about Restricting usage for an Android key.

Comment: @KENdi thank you for your response. I have no idea how to mark your comment as an acceptable response though? I appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't know if this is a bug or not. But according to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740251/youtube-api-v3-always-return-error-403-accessnotconfigured) it might be a bug in the Google System. The only workaround that I see in the internet for this issue is by using a Browser key instead of Android key. If you have time, try also to check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33989062/restricting-usage-for-an-android-key-for-a-google-api) about Restricting usage for an Android key